# Could not build Objective-C module 'ChameleonFramework'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, swift5

I am trying to include the ChameleonFramework in my project but it shows this message:

`Could not build Objective-C module 'ChameleonFramework'`

I install the framework using cocoapods and solve like 49 errors in the code because I'm using Swift 5 and Xcode 12.2.

Also, I delete the cache for the project, uninstall the pods and install them from the console, but still not working.

Comment: See the first answer here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128535 - maybe it is useful for your project as well.

Comment: I run those steps in my project but still not working. I think it is something wrong with the version but still can't find it.

Comment: Possibly, project hasn't been updated for over 4 years. Did you ask the developer?

Comment: Not yet.  I'm still working in the functionality